# split with no white space in string in android java

Tags: java, android, string

String like this:

```
String valuetest="%%%%%";
```

Empty value after each %. it means "value"%"value"%...so on. in
above empty ,every % sign followed by here empty string. i followed by this tutorials but could not getting proper idea: [Split with character * in string java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379760/split-with-character-in-string-java)

**Here i want to split value on the basis of %.**

i have here five empty value.

```
String[] splitvalue = valuetest.split("\\%");
```

but getting empty string array.

Thank in advance.

Comment: where is your dateValue?Can you post some code?

Comment: does it help http://stackoverflow.com/a/20443511/1393766? `split("%",-1)`

Comment: what is your dateValue? for the valuetest it should be empty as there is nothing between % separators

Comment: I think you valuetest not contain any space try this way : String valuetest=" % % % % %";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returned value is correct as there is nothing between % separators. For example for value "1%2%%4" it should return {"1", "2", "", "4"} array.